# Putting together first a variable and then text

Tags: c#, razor

I have a form I want the name of the input to be the day of the week the variable represents and then Beg so for example if it represents Sunday it should be SundayBeg.

```
 name='@l.Day"+ Beg"'
```

How do I do this?

Comment: var name=string.Format("{0}Beg",System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to put it into a string like your example, and assuming that `l.Day` is the value you want to concatenate with "Beg"...

```
var name = $"{l.Day}Beg";
```

***EDIT:*** It's been pointed out that string interpolation does not play nice in Razor views. I am leaving this example here for posterity, but removing it from my example below.

Or if you're not using C#6...

```
var name = string.Format("{0}Beg", l.Day);
```

Then, you just display the value of `name` wherever you wish. Based on your example, I'm guessing you want to use the value as the `name` property of some HTML element. So you would do it like so:

```
<input name="@name" ... />
```

You could also just do it all in-line in place of using a variable.

```
<input name="@string.Format("{0}Beg", l.Day)" ... />
```

Comment: I didn't realize he was going for Razor syntax - would my answer also work if he were to use the @name and use it where he needs it?  There are always a few ways to do things!

Comment: when I try this, name="@$"{l.Day}Beg"",           I get this "$" is not valid at the start of a code block. But the second one works. So Thanks!!

Comment: @confusedandamused Yeah, that wasn't really obvious. The only reason I picked up on that was the fact that he posted this question with the MVC tag, and his usage of the `@` symbol. Yours would work too, but I think it's rarely correct to use "+" when forming or building or concatenating strings. Using string interpolation or `string.Format()` is preferrable.

Comment: @EricSondergard Thanks for the clarification I'll start doing that from now on - As for his issue with the $ not being valid - That's a string interpolation issue in Razor view then, right?

Comment: @N.Sch Okay. I thought the razor syntax might gripe about that, which is why I mentioned it. I will edit my answer appropriately. Does `string.Format()` work for you?

Comment: @confusedandamused Yes, or he's not using C#6. I don't know which, but I've never tried string interpolation in a Razor view, let alone in-line, so I anticipated there might be a conflict like that. See this doc for more info on string interpolation in C#: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/24/c-sharp-6-0-features/49/string-interpolation#t=201609291914005603791

Comment: Nice job @EricSondergard Cheers +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

`var name = System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek + " Beg"`

Assuming you're using the current day of the week.

[Docs Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hmm I guess I wasn't clear. Not a variable. The name attribute in an input field.

Comment: The ToString is redundant.

Comment: @CSharpie Removed - Thanks!